# migrating from mod_python into mod_wsgi (multiple projects)

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, mod-python

After upgrade to jessie my django stops working. I found that problem is in mod_python, so I decided that this is good reason to migrate to mod_wsgi. 
I read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) but i'm not sure what to do if i got more than one project:

I got few projects in /home folder:

- /home/project1
- /home/project2
- /home/project3

my apache's http.conf (not migrated to 2.4 yet, so please ignore Order/allow etc)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
      <Location "/project1">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE project1.settings
        PythonInterpreter project1
        PythonOption django.root /project1
        PythonDebug On
        PythonPath "['/home', '/home/project1'] + sys.path"
      </Location>
      <Location "/project2">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE project2.settings
        PythonInterpreter project2
        PythonOption django.root /project2
        PythonDebug On
        PythonPath "['/home', '/home/project2'] + sys.path"
      </Location>
      <Location "/project3">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE project3.settings
        PythonInterpreter project3
        PythonOption django.root /project3
        PythonDebug On
        PythonPath "['/home', '/home/project3'] + sys.path"
      </Location>


      Alias /admin_media/ /usr/share/pyshared/django/contrib/admin/media/
      Alias /static/ /home/common/

      ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
      <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
         Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm thinking about daemon mode, but how to use it on different projects???

**Update**
According to @GrahamDumpleton's answer my new apache looks like:

ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www
 <Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
 <Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
 WSGIDaemonProcess project1
 WSGIDaemonProcess project2
 WSGIDaemonProcess project3


 WSGIScriptAlias /project1/ /home/project1/wsgi.py process-group=project1
 WSGIScriptAlias /project2/ /home/project2/wsgi.py process-group=project2
 WSGIScriptAlias /project3/ /home/project3/wsgi.py process-group=project3


 <Directory /home/*>
   Require all granted
 </Directory>

 Alias /admin_media/ /usr/share/pyshared/django/contrib/admin/media/
 Alias /static/ /home/common/

 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
 <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
   AllowOverride None
   Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
  <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now it works - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your projects are all at separate sub URLs, simply use multiple `WSGIScriptAlias` directives, one for each sub URL. And definitely use a daemon process group for each distinct Django instance.

For some additional reading see:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html

There are also the mod_wsgi docs, although they are in a slight mess right now.

Comment: WSGIApplicationGroup ? Is it useless for me?

Comment: If using ``WSGIScriptAlias`` for everything and ``process-group`` option is always used with it, then yes, ``WSGIProcessGroup`` is not needed as the ``process-group`` option takes precedence for that WSGI application. BTW, since you have each in its own daemon process group, also add ``application-group=%{GLOBAL}`` to the ``WSGIScriptAlias`` at the end. This will ensure the use of main interpreter context of respective processes, which avoids problems with certain third party modules for Python which don't work in sub interpreters.